# Uniqueness of the form of solution for a given homogeneous second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How does one prove that if $f$ is a twice differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ and is a solution to

$$f''(t)+ c^{2} f(t) = 0$$

then there are no solutions other than

$$f(t)=a\cos(ct)+b\sin(ct)$$

where $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: See [here](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-034-honors-differential-equations-spring-2009/lecture-notes-and-readings/MIT18_034s09_lec08.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
You can show this by solving the characteristic equation of this ODE $x^2+c^2=0$, then $x=\pm ci$.

Comment: The OP was asking for a uniqueness proof.